# phonegap msbuild failed in windows phone 8

Tags: cordova

I get the following error when I run

```
phonegap local build wp8

M:\LocalDevelopment\PhoneGap\HelloWorldW>phonegap local build wp8
[phonegap] adding the Windows Phone 8 platform...
   [error] Requirements check failed: The command `msbuild` failed. Make sure you have the latest Windows Phone SDKs ins
talled, AND have the latest .NET framework added to your path (i.e C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319).
```

I've noticed a few other people with the same issue so ive changed the check_reqs.js file in the .cordova dir but it's still the same. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ensure what the error says? That you have the SDK's installed and have the latest .NET Framework in your path?

Answer (score 3):

Run command prompt:

Start > Run > [type] `cmd`

In here, enter:

`msbuild -v`

Observe whether it returns the version number, or a `command not found` error. Hopefully the latter, if so - then you will need to add `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework[64]\<VERSION>\MSBuild.exe` to your path.

Comment: can you reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386379/cordova-phonegap-application-crashes-when-using-device-plugin-with-windows-phone about windows & phonegap