# cordova/phonegap application crashes when using device plugin with windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I installed the **device** plugin using this command line from my application directory:

**plugman install --plugin org.apache.cordova.device --platform wp8 --project .**

However when I try and use device this way:

```
console.log( "device.platform: " + device.platform );
```

my App crashes with this error:

*The thread 0xfc8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).*

Please what is wrong with this? Am I missing anything?

Comment: did you run `cordova build` after adding the plugin?

Comment: I followed this: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html, shall I execute cordova build in such case?

Comment: Yes, you have to run the build command to have the plugin added to the platforms. the plugin command just adds the plugin files to the project, but not each added platform

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, from where should I run cordova build? I didnt use CLI but plugman. I get this message from my project dir (No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`)

Comment: oh, sorry I assumed you were using the CLI. It really is very helpful, I would recommend trying it if you are able to.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon, CLI for win seems to be broken as well, because I got this error message  "Building Windows Phone application using MSBuild 64 bit is not supported." when trying to build for wp8

Comment: in Cordova version 3.6, they fixed my bug (MSBuild 64) now I can use CLI and it works!